# how to construct this function using identities

Tags: functional-equations

Given that
$f(\sin x)+f(\cos x)= \tan x$.

My attempt to find $f(x)$ is by guessing terms to meet the condition. Please help.

Note $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So looking at $x = \pi/6$, we have

\begin{align}
f(\sin \pi/6) + f (\cos \pi/6) &= \tan \pi/6 \\
f(0.5) + f(0.866...) &\approx .577,
\end{align}
but for $x = \pi/3$, we get
\begin{align}
f(\sin \pi/3) + f (\cos \pi/3) &= \tan \pi/3 \\
f(0.866...) + f(0.5) &\approx 1.73.
\end{align}

That just can't happen, because addition is commutative.

Comment: Okay if you say so